# Formulize this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

There is this function defined as;

$$f(x) = 10^x + 10^{x-1} +  ...+10^0  $$

Which simply gives the 111.. kind of number, given the length x. What I need to do is a way to formulize this function, find the result value with an algebraic expression. Is this achievable ?

Comment: Yes. Assuming $x$ are integers then this is simply a [geometric series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given function is a geometric summation with first term $1$ and ratio $10$. Thus
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^x 10^n = \frac{10^{x+1}-1}{10-1}=\frac{10^{x+1}-1}{9}
$$

Comment: Cannot believe I missed that :( Thanks, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Your series is the sum of the terms of a Geometric progression.

Comment: Thank you. One should not forget high school math.

Comment: It is if $x $ is an integer. Why should a length be an integer?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, but I think OP got the idea

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

- $$\sum_{k=a}^{n}b^{m-k}=\frac{b^{m-n-a}\left(b^{n+1}-b^a\right)}{b-1}$$

---

$$f(x)=10^x+10^{x-1}+\dots+10^0=10^{x-0}+10^{x-1}+\dots+10^{x-x}=$$
$$\sum_{k=2}^{x}10^{2-k}=\frac{10-10^{2-x}}{9}$$